# Magento 2 : Skip exception

Tags: magento2, refund

Is their any way we can continue execution of program
after below exception

```
throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                __('If the invoice was created offline, try creating an offline credit memo.'),
                                $e
                            );
```

Actually i have created an shipment refund script that refunds shipment for orders.
i pass order id in csv & it created online credit memo.
But for some order (that i don't know).
get stuck in below exception, That is why the next order id does not gets executed.
Is their any way i can skip this exception or check something in script to prevent call going into this code ?

```
Magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php

throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                __('If the invoice was created offline, try creating an offline credit memo.'),
                                $e
                            );
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ? –

Comment: Try to create a credit memo in the  admin. There's a checkbox to make it an offline credit memo. This checkbox is posted to the server. Post this checkbox value in your script.

Comment: Thankyou for the advice,
checking that checkbox will result into "offline refund" & i need to process refund online.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see the script in order to have a better opinion.But I imagine that you are looping the CSV Items and calling a method that  Payment class  throws the exception.

Lets suppose that you have that loop:

```
foreach ($csvOrders as $csvOrder){
....
     try {
            // Call vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php method

     } catch (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e ) {
            // Log the error $e->getMessage()
     }
}
```

It will process all the orders and save the errors on log file, then you can track the issue of others.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that payment.php executes this code - throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                __('If the invoice was created offline, try creating an offline credit memo.'),
                                $e
                            );
That just stop execution further.

Comment: Can you share the script? it can give us some clue.

Comment: Yes  - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339283/magento-2-error-if-the-invoice-was-created-offline-try-creating-an-offline-c

Comment: I realized that your code is catching the interpreter exception: \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException.   However Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException is a runtime exception, that is a different type and level. Please, try to change the NoSuchEntityException by Exception that catches all the exceptions and it must work.