# Magento 2 : Error "Unable to create credit memo for order"

Tags: magento2, sales-order, invoice, creditmemo, refund

I am getting this error while online refunding credit memo using a script.

"Unable to create credit memo for order" error appear, this is due to this
https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/89adbabc2a295c9b6f88768d541fd2858f59aae5/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php#L603

I want to know in which conditions, this error come ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Maybe just put breakpoint in canCreditmemo function, and check, where exactly it returns false? There are like 5 `ifs` to check. So You have like 5 or 6 possibilities.. Check Order status. Is it mached to any requirement in one of `if`? What about TotalPaid and Refunded? If You can use xdebug, just check manually all `ifs` and compare to current state of order. YOu can also check MagentoDev for Credit Memo https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/sales/credit-memo-create.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, appreciate it

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Hey, there is no possibility that anyone here will know know that... There are like 6 condition. Issue may come from every single one. It depends on order and order current configuration / status. Without more information about order and possible shop configuration, noone will answer You...

Comment: Right, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debug code step by step, add logs in your main logic
after line by line.
Check from where the logic fails.
This error is caused when there is no item passed to refund array
(`ordered item id`) should be passed in order to process refund.

Answer (score 2):

See this for how flag `ForcedCanCreditmemo` property was set. Note that this property is just for current instance not a field in database, also cannot be saved.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Payment/Observer/SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.php

It seem like Creditmemo for free transactions is not possible.

But if you might want to customize it, add this flag on observer event `sales_order_load_after`

```
if($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() === 'free') {
    $order->setForcedCanCreditmemo(true);
}
```